# cant insert objects in a doubly linked list due to an null pointer exception

Tags: java

I'm trying to compare the size of two UF components and after doing this comparison I want to insert the object in the specific location if it's even or odd otherwise..But i cant insert any because I get an null pointer exception and I can't understand why i cant iterate through objects.

```
DoublyLinkedList<WeightedQuickUnionUF> list = new DoublyLinkedList<WeightedQuickUnionUF>();
ListIterator<WeightedQuickUnionUF> iterator = list.iterator();
public void add(WeightedQuickUnionUF item){
    if(component%2==0){
        if(list.isEmpty()){
            list.add(item);
        }
        else if(!iterator.hasPrevious()) list.add(item);
        else if(iterator.hasPrevious()) {
            while(iterator.hasPrevious()){
                WeightedQuickUnionUF xf = iterator.previous();
                int x = xf.getSize();
                System.out.println(x);
                if(x<component){
                    iterator.set(item);
                }
            }
        }
        else iterator.set(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: What line  do you get NPE?

Comment: `else if(!iterator.hasPrevious())` or `else if(iterator.hasPrevious())`  ... it's sounds like "to be or not to be" ... you never get the else clause ( `iterator.set(item)` ) I think..

Comment: NPE shows up when the program tries to enter an odd item.. the rest of the code is the same only it checks for an odd element